# Image Resizing and Compression

Tags: php, image

I'm implementing an image upload facility for my website. The uploading facility is complete but what I'm working on at the moment is manipulating the images. For this task I am using PHPThumb (http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com).

Anyway as I go along I'm coming across potential issues, to do with resizing and compression. Basically I want to acheive the following results:

1. The ideal image dimensions are: 800px width, 600px height. If an uploaded image exceeds either of these dimensions, it will need be resized to meet the requirements. Otherwise, leave as it is.
2. The ideal file size is 200kb. If an uploaded image exceeds this then it will need to be compressed to meet this requirement. Otherwise, leave as it is.

So in a nutshell: 1) Check the dimensions, resize if required. 2) Check the filesize, compress if required.

Has anybody done anything like this / could you give me some pointers? Is PHPThumb the correct tool to do this in?

Answer (score 4):

As long as I can see just from the docs, phpThumb should be good enough for this task.
phpThumb can be used in an easy way like this:

> Call phpThumb() just like you would a normal image.
>   Examples:

```
<IMG SRC="phpThumb.php?src=/image.jpg&w=100">
<IMG SRC="phpThumb.php?src=http://example.com/foo.jpg">
```

> See the "demo" link on
>   http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net for
>   more usage examples). Parameters that
>   can be passed are listed below under
>   "URL Parameters".

The phpThumb() website says that it has the following image-processing feature:

> Quality can be auto-adjusted to fit a certain output byte size.

This looks like what you want. It works by passing a maximum byte size parameter. The [readme](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/docs/phpthumb.readme.txt) tells you how:

> maxb = MAXimum Byte size - output quality is auto-set to
>          fit thumbnail into "maxb" bytes  (compression
>          quality is adjusted for JPEG, bit depth is adjusted
>          for PNG and GIF)

*edit: it seems that we were talking about different utilities with the same name. I did not found the same functionality in the other one, so I can only recommend using what I've found.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I think that is a different version of PHPThumb, the one that I am using is: http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/

Comment: @GSTAR Please edit your original post to reflect this; it's too bad that there're different projects with the same name.

Comment: Done. Sorry about the confusion there.

Answer (score 0):

See the [gd extension](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), in particular the functions [`getimagesize`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and [`imagecopyresized`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php).

Enforcing a file size is more difficult, the best you can do is stick with jpeg and some arbitrary level of compression; for a certain combination of dimensions+compression, you can more or less predict the final file size of the image.

As to PHPThumb, I have no idea, as I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks mate. Yeah I understand it would be diffcult to enforce a file size. How would I check the file size anyhow? I suppose I can apply the compression level based on the file size.